# Edit in Jquery Dialogue using ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I Have a Jquery Dialog that I want use to edit information, but I need ajax to populate the info that I will edit in the textboxes but it seems my ajax call has problems as its not retrieving the info  I think the problem lies with the response, can someone please review my code thank you.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
       function ShowDialog(RowID) {
      //alert(RowID);
      $("#EditTable").dialog({
          autoOpen: true,
          width: 300,
          height: 300,
          modal: true,

          open: function () {
              $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  url: 'TestMultipleWebMail.aspx/EditRecord',
                  data: '{"RowID":"' + RowID + '"}',
                  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                  dataType: "json",
                  async: "true",
                  success: function (msg) {
                      var msg = eval('(' + response.d + ')');

                      $("#Esupartnerno").val(msg.SUPartnerNo);
                      $("#Ename").val(msg.UserName);
                      $("#Eemail").val(msg.EMail);
                      $("#Ebranchno").val(msg.TakNo);
                  },
                  error: function (response) {
                      alert(response.status + '' + response.statusText);
                  }
              });
          },
          buttons:
          {
              "Cancel": function () {
                  $(this).dialog("close");
              },

              "Update": function () {

              }
          }
      });

    }
   </script>


    [WebMethod] /// edit
    public static string EditRecord(string RowID)
    {
        string data = string.Empty;

        BLDAL blDAL = new BLDAL(BLDAL.GetConnectionString(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ConnectionString")));

        blDAL.LoadMultipleWebMailGetinfo(RowID);


        return data;
       }
```

Comment: Nope, people will not review your code. Be more specific with regards to exception/error/unexpected behaviour details. What line causes you problems?

Comment: This line cause the problem.       success: function (msg) {
                      var msg = eval('(' + response.d + ')');

Comment: And what's the problem? Have you checked response has the value you'd expect?